# MongoDB execute script returns _mongo and _db information

Tags: kohana-mangodb

I'm executing a MongoDB script via the Kohana MangoDB ORM.

Here's the code to be executed:

```
var query {
    date: date
};
var indexes = db.organisation_booking_indexes.find(query);
```

If I do `.findOne(query)` I get the specific result as an array. However just doing `.find(query)` returns other stuff like `_mongo` and `_db` instead of an array of the expected results.

How do I return just the documents I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that some objects can't be returned "as is" using JS.
In this case Mongo return the Cursor

Try:

```
var indexes = db.organisation_booking_indexes.find(query).toArray();
```

This will convert the result in a "compatible" object.
Take a look at this post to get more  details:
[MongoDB: Error executing stored JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700948/mongodb-error-executing-stored-javascript-function)